# Read Windows login username with Ada 95

Tags: ada

Is there a function in Ada 95 which returns me a String containing the logged username in an Windows application?
Thanks.

Comment: The language (like C++) has no concept in its standard for "users" or "logins". As such, you may want to rephrase this question a bit to avoid a lot of pedantic "that isn't base Ada functionality" answers. Perhaps something like, "How can I get the name of the logged-in Windows user from my Ada program? I'm using the *XYZ* compiler."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the idea from @KeithThompson comment, plus @SimonWright USERNAME suggestion, one way to do it is using the code:

```
function GetUsername return String is
   function GetEnv (Variable : String) return Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr;
   pragma Import (C, GetEnv, "getenv");

   Command : constant String := "USERNAME";
   Answer_Ptr : constant Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr := GetEnv (Command);
   Answer : constant String := Interfaces.C.Strings.Value (Answer_Ptr);
begin
   return Answer;
end GetUsername;
```

Not pure Ada 95, but it fits well (and I don't have to use gnat05 switch).

Answer (score 3):

The general answer is to use whatever mechanism your Ada environment supports to call native Win32 API functions, and to call the [`GetUserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: All the Ada 95 standard says about this is section [B.3 Interfacing with C](http://www.adahome.com/rm95/rm9x-B-03.html). Your Ada environment on Windows will have documentation describing how to use these facilities to call Win32 API functions.

Answer (score 2):

The GNAT specific package [`Ada.Command_Line.Environment`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gnat_rm/Ada_002eCommand_005fLine_002eEnvironment-_0028a_002dcolien_002eads_0029.html#Ada_002eCommand_005fLine_002eEnvironment-_0028a_002dcolien_002eads_0029) may be an available alternative.

Answer (score 2):

If you were allowed to use Ada 2005, you could use the package [Ada.Environment_Variables](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-17.html) to get the value of `USERNAME` (I think that's the right env var for Windows? it's `USER` on Darwin ...)

Comment: Or you can use `pragma Import(C, getenv);`

Comment: The problem with relying on an environment variable is that it's trivial to forge. (So is `GetUserName`, but less trivially.)